# Troubleshooting 802.1x authentication issue relating to signal strength

Tags: radius

My setup:

- Windows 2008 R2 server with the NPS role configured for RADIUS _PEAP/MSCHAPV2.
- I have a WPA2 Enterprise network configured on the Ubiquity controller.
- 3 Ubiquity UniFi LR access points.

At certain distances from an access point, and although the signal appears strong *4 out of 5 bars* connection attempts from my mobile phone *using that as a testing tool*, do not seem to get past the "Connecting" message. When I get close enough I would go through "Authenticating" and then "Connected".

My question is: Would having such a wireless configuration pose a minimum signal strength requirement to allow for successfully connecting to the network? Is there something maybe in NPS that specifies a minimum signal strength? 
Thank you